# Failed to delete Perforce client workspace with error message "client is locked, cannot be deleted"

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to delete a workspace (client) in Perforce, so I type

```
p4 client -d my-client
```

but I get the error message

> client is locked, cannot be deleted

How do I unlock the workspace so it can be deleted?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to edit the client spec. Type

```
p4 client my-client
```

This will put you in an editor with the client spec. Find the "Options:" section, change "locked" to "unlocked", and save the file. You should now be able to delete the workspace.

Comment: This doesn't work with 2022.1. This command creates a temporary file in the temp directory and saving it has no effect.

Answer (score 9):

In p4v:

1. Right click the workspace, select "Edit workspace my-client".
2. Advanced Tab
3. Uncheck "Locked: only the owner..."

You should be able to delete it now.

Comment: This works, but only if the client doesn't have any files opened or checked-out.